# PHP - Secure MySQL Login

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a PHP function that any other function on my server goes to to connect to a global MySQL database:

```
function connect_to_mysql_db() {

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user_name", "password");
if (!$con)
   {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);

}
```

The file which holds this function, as well as most of the others, is located in the following location on my BlueHost server:

```
/home3/username/includes/scripts.php
```

The database currently holds only one table with a list of email addresses (those of my subscribers...) I just want to know if the database is secure (for the sake of my subscribers)

If not, does anyone have any other ideas (encryption?). I know HASHING won't work because that is usually 1-way...

**EDIT**

FYI: The **/includes/** directory is not **/public_html/**

**CONCLUSION**

Thank you to all who helped me, but I decided that there is just too much liabilities for no good reason, so I will not be storing anything secure in a database. Instead, I will use external services!

Cheers!

Comment: Do you want to know whether connecting to a database the way you currently do it is secure?

Comment: I don't think you understand what "security" means.

Comment: Well, security does not depend on a single factor. Your script, that holds the credentials to your database, might be perfectly secure when inspected separately. But any single vulnerability in your system can undermine the whole security and pose a threat to the data that is stored in it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will give you any additional security.
If someone hacks your server, reads the scripts to get the database credentials, logs into mysql, reads the mailadressen and gets only encrypted data, he will probably take a second look into the scripts for the decryption key...

So, I think this is not going to make it way more secure. You better focus on writing a secure environment to prevent any access to the server ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's secure enough. Anyway if you want more, try something like this:

```
$crypted = openssl_encrypt ('myemail' ,'AES256', 'mypass')
```

and then

```
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt ($crypted, 'AES256', 'mypass')
```

Reference  [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php).

Answer (score -2):

You could AES encrypt the email addresses. 
ie:

`$query = "INSERT INTO (table) AES_ENCRYPT('$email', '$salt')..."`

To get the email back in normal text:

`$query = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT('email', '$salt') FROM (table) WHERE 1..."`

$salt would be a randomly generated key that you put into the variable.

The column in you database table needs to be a blob.

Comment: Tip: php side encryption allows 256 bit AES, mysql side only 128.

Comment: 2 Things: 1) Do I have to define '$salt'? 2) What is a _blob_? Thanks!!! I'm a n00b!

Comment: **ALSO** I have an ID column so how would I do the INSERT statement?

Comment: I also have seen one way encrypt, I don't know if it's better or worse, but it's another solution

Comment: Salt is just an encryption/decryption key you use to store and view the data. You can use pretty much anything for it. A blob is a binary column type in MySQL; you'll see it when you're creating tables in phpmyadmin or whatever you use. Here's a tutorial on it: http://techpad.co.uk/content.php?sid=82

Comment: @StevenBuick A salt an a encryption key are not the same. A salt is used to make the input of a hashing function unique and is not a secret while an encryption key is to be kept secret as, well, it’s the key to the encryption.

Comment: I was using 'encryption/decryption key' to illustrate the job of the salt. It might be semantically wrong but so is calling AES a 'hashing' function as it's two-way encryption.

Comment: a 'Salt' is not a 'Key'. A 'salt' is defined as 'a random set of bits of fixed length' and need not be kept secret. A 'key' is a secret set of bits.